# Anyone have solutions for table>th with position:sticky not working on FF & IE?

Tags: css, sapui5

I have an idea to make sticky header of table and I have tried with position:sticky. It's
 working fine on Chrome but on Firefox and IE not working as I think. Below is my CSS

```
.myTable--mof thead th {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index:100;
}
```

Comment: Firefox supports it on versions 32 & above. For IE you might have to use a Polyfill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position:sticky` is not supported for child table elements in some browsers. The 'why' I don't know.. Will it be supported in the future? I sure hope so!

I recently wrote this jQuery solution. It'll work for simple tables with simple headers. `Does not look for colspans or multiple rows in thead!`

I tried some plugins before, but they all listened for the scroll event which throws alerts in some browsers. They caused flickering/jumping in some cases, and a delay was noticable when hitting the position to stick at.

Using `position:sticky` for other elements and liking those transitions more, I came up with the following piece of code.

```
jQuery.fn.stickTableHeaders = function() {
    return this.each(function()
    {
        var table = $(this),
        header = table.find('thead'),
        sticked = $('<table></table>').addClass('table').append(header.clone()); // Needs to be wrapped in new table since table child elements can't be sticky? (FF)

        sticked.find('th').css({ // You'll have to copy the original thead (th's) CSS manualy
            'backgroundColor': '#DEE5EA',
            'color': '#606060',
            'padding':'8px',
            'color':'#606060'
        }).removeAttr('width'); // And remove the width attr from the clone th's since we'll be setting them again later

        sticked.find('th:not(:last-child)').css({ // More CSS
            'borderRight': '1px solid #ddd'
        });

        sticked.find('a').css({ // More CSS
            'color':'#606060'
        });

        // I tried different things, most of the original th's should have a width attribute set (not in CSS and avoid percent) for best results
        $(window).resize(function() {
            sticked.width(table.width());
            sticked.find('th').each(function() {
                var headerTH = header.find('th').eq($(this).index());
                if(headerTH.is('[width]') || headerTH.is(':first-child') || headerTH.is(':last-child')) { // First and last th are allready calculated by another function in my app. See what suits for you here...
                    $(this).width(header.find('th').eq($(this).index()).width());
                }
                else {
                    var cellWidth = header.find('th').eq($(this).index()).width(true),
                    tableWidth = table.width(true),
                    percent = 100*(cellWidth/tableWidth);
                    $(this).css({'width':percent+'%'});
                }
            });

            // We keep the original thead to avoid table collapsing, we just slide the whole table up.
            table.css({
                'marginTop':-header.height()
            });
        }).trigger('resize');

        // Apply stickyness 
        sticked.css({
            'display':'table',
            'position':'sticky',
            'top':$('#header-menu').height(), // My sticky nav is my top position, adjust this to your needs
            'zIndex':'10'
        });

        // Insert clone before original table
        $(this).before(sticked);
    });
};
```

Now I just use this on each page load:

```
$("table").stickTableHeaders();
```

You might want to filter out nested tables from the above selector...

Hope this helps someone.